# Oracle Weblogic server 10.3.6 - Data source Connection pool issue

Tags: java, database, oracle, server, weblogic

So we started migrating all our code changes in a desktop. After every code is in place (server is up etc) Then tried to browse the localhost. An exception is encountered.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.pg.sam.ui.framework.SAMBaseAction.validateUser(SAMBaseAction.java:215)
```

The Problem is that the application is not communicating with the weblogic server. I checked our previous logs before and each time that the user browses the localhost, this entry is created.

Here's what was happening in a different computer. each time the localhost is entered a connection pool is established:

[image]

While in the new desktop. No connection pool is established resulting in the null pointer exception:

[image]

any help will do. I've double checked weblogic.xml, web.xml everything and all files are totally in sync with the other desktop. I have no idea why the connection pool is not working on the other one. thanks!

Comment: Why do you think no connection pool is established, or why it's directly related? The stack trace in the second mage doesn't seem to refer to the pool. (It's much easier to read these things if you post the text rather than an image). It may be hitting an error before it even tries, though it's maybe more likely the Info message is just earlier in the log.

Comment: Here's the full server log

Comment: https://sites.google.com/a/uap.asia/genez/links/AdminServer.log Thanks for the support

Comment: Line 542 of that looks like it's cerated the pool, just before the exception at 547. I don't think any of the errors, starting at 326, are related to the pool, the early ones just precede it being created? (Maybe you [have a patch missing](http://soa-made-easy.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/not-able-to-access-osb-proxy-service.html)? No idea really... good luck!)

Comment: yeah it was able to create the pool but the assigned user is (WLS Kernel) not the user which I logged on... Weird I know. Thanks I'll try to access that patch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

deployed earfile was not properly deployed (Don't know why) I just redeployed the ear file and everything was woring.